# Unable to load dvb-usb-rtl2832u driver in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, dvb-t

I am trying to setup a Compro U680F USB DVB-T adaptor in Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel
3.2.0-29-generic).

The compro device ID is given (lsusb) as 185b:0680. The following page suggests
this device is supported by the RT2832U driver:
http://www.dfragos.me/2011/11/installation-of-the-rt2832u-driver-in-linux/

I successfully built the v4l-dvb package from source following this how to,
using the "Basic Approach": 
http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers

After restarting the system the device does not appear to be working. The
output from "lsmod | grep dvb" is as follows:

```
root@DCTbox:/home/dct# lsmod | grep dvb 
dvb_usb               32369   0
dvb_core              110590  1 dvb_usb 
rc_core               26343   1 dvb_usb
```

If I unplug the device and plug back in, I get the following from "dmesg |
tail":

```
root@DCTbox:/home/dct# dmesg | tail -n 27
[  160.015155] usb 5-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  160.051152] usb 5-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep
desc says 0 microframes
[  160.133825] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media
stack.
[  160.133826]     As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't
offer
[  160.133827]     enough quality for its usage in production.
[  160.133828]     Use it with care.
[  160.133829] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to
linux-media@vger.kernel.org):
[  160.133830]     9b78c5a3007e10a172d4e83bea18509fdff2e8e3 [media] b2c2:
export b2c2_flexcop_debug symbol
[  160.133832]     88f8472c9fc6c08f5113887471f1f4aabf7b2929 [media] Fix some
Makefile rules
[  160.133833]     893430558e5bf116179915de2d3d119ad25c01cf [media]
cx23885-cards: fix netup card default revision
[  160.144374] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media
stack.
[  160.144376]     As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't
offer
[  160.144377]     enough quality for its usage in production.
[  160.144378]     Use it with care.
[  160.144379] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to
linux-media@vger.kernel.org):
[  160.144380]     9b78c5a3007e10a172d4e83bea18509fdff2e8e3 [media] b2c2:
export b2c2_flexcop_debug symbol
[  160.144381]     88f8472c9fc6c08f5113887471f1f4aabf7b2929 [media] Fix some
Makefile rules
[  160.144383]     893430558e5bf116179915de2d3d119ad25c01cf [media]
cx23885-cards: fix netup card default revision
[  160.173311] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: disagrees about version of symbol
dvb_usb_device_init
[  160.173315] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: Unknown symbol dvb_usb_device_init (err -22)
[  392.860811] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: disagrees about version of symbol
dvb_usb_device_init
[  392.860815] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: Unknown symbol dvb_usb_device_init (err -22)
[ 1282.328055] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1288.697208] usb 5-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 1288.732785] usb 5-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep
desc says 0 microframes
[ 1288.747585] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: disagrees about version of symbol
dvb_usb_device_init
[ 1288.747589] dvb_usb_rtl2832u: Unknown symbol dvb_usb_device_init (err -22)
```

If I attempt to load the driver manually I get the following error message:

```
root@DCTbox:/home/dct# modprobe dvb_usb_rtl2832u
FATAL: Error inserting dvb_usb_rtl2832u
(/lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-usb/dvb-usb-rtl2832u.ko):
Invalid argument
```

Any advice on how to get this device working successfully would be greatly
appreciated.

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Try either:

[ambrosa / DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0](https://github.com/ambrosa/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0)

[tmair / DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0](https://github.com/tmair/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0)

I have a **Terratec** *Cinergy TStick+* (ID 0ccd:00d7).

Neither of these worked for me, and I instead had to use **media build** driver.

*However, your device may work ..*

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately in the end I replaced the tuner with one with better support so am unable to test.